# Switch function on moving row script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script that I'm trying to merge several moving scripts into one single function.

I got the tip to use the switch function which I think is a good idea but I haven't use that function before in script and I can't get it to work.

So I need help to see what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is how it works:

The script will move rows to different sheets within the spreadsheet depending on which Col is edited.

In the example spreadsheet I have these Col's:

- Col 7 (Återkomster) - In this one I put in a date and the row will be
  moved to the sheet "Återkomster"
- Col 8 (Bokad) - In this one I put in    a date and the row will be
  moved to the sheet "Bokad"
- Col 9 (Nej) -    In this one i put in 1 and the row will be moved to
  the sheet "Nej"
- Col    10 (Avtal) - In this one I put in a date and the row will be
  moved to    the sheet "Avtal"

Here is a link to a dummy sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HzLRtSFULijIVbtW8xcIPDOgQKCYdQ4TLN2FgEtSqIg/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the script:

```js
function allInOne(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = e.range;
  var sheet = range.sheet;
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  if (e.value != "") {
    if (sheetName == "Pipe") {
      switch (r.getColumn()) {
        case 7:
          // if (r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() != "") {  // you don't need this because the "if (e.value != "")" above and the "case" takes care of it
          var row = r.getRow();
          var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
          var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Återkomster");
          var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
          s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target).range.clearContent();

        // 
      // do column 7 tasks
      break;

        case 8:
      // if (r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() != "") 
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Bokad");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target).range.clearContent();

      // 
      // do column 8 tasks
      break;

      case 9:
      // if (r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() != "") 
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Bokad");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target).range.clearContent();

      // 
      // do column 8 tasks
      break;

        case 13:
      // if (r.getColumn() == 10 && r.getValue() != "") 
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Avtal");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target).range.clearContent();

      // 
      // do column 13 tasks
      break;

        default:
      // do nothing because the edit is happening on a column we don't want to watch
      return;
    
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: This `var sheet = range.sheet;` should be `var sheet = range.getSheet();`

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `range` and `s` are not declared. By this, unfortunately, your script doesn't correctly work.
- I thought that in your script, the script might be able to be simpler using an object and the event object.
- I thought that in your script, a simple trigger can be used.
- In your question, you say `Col 9 (Nej) - In this one i put in 1 and the row will be moved to the sheet "Nej"`. But, in your script, when column 9 is edited, "Bokad" is used.
- `moveTo` method of Class Range returns no value. So, `moveTo(target).range.clearContent()` cannot be used.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your provided Spreadsheet, and save the script. When you use this script, please put a value to after column "G" in the sheet "Pipe". By this, the script is run.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const obj = { "7": "Återkomster", "8": "Bokad", "9": "Nej", "13": "Avtal" }; // This is from your question.
  const { range, source } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const dstSheetName = obj[range.columnStart];
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Pipe" || range.columnStart < 7 || range.rowStart == 1 || range.isBlank() || !dstSheetName) return;
  const srcRow = sheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 2, 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 1);
  const dstSheet = source.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  const dstRow = dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  srcRow.moveTo(dstRow);
  // sheet.deleteRow(range.rowStart); // If you want to delete the moved row, please use this line.
}
```

- In this script, when the cell after column "G" in "Pipe" sheet is edited, the row is moved to each sheet declared by `obj`.
- In your script, the edited row is moved. If you want to delete the edited row, please use the last line in my script.

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided sample Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: @Eric Morandeau Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.